# How to check whether the variable is the same data type for if else statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently creating a function for simple online shop
which requires the user to check whether their age is above 18.
However, I can't figure out how to check if the user input is an integer or string. I would appreciate any help.

```
def input_age():
    age = int(input('Please enter your age\n'))
    if age <= 18:
        print('Sorry, you are too young. Don\'t shop with us.')
        quit()
    elif isinstance(age,int): #Check whether age is int
        print('Please insert numbers only')
        input_age()
    elif age > 18:
        name = str(input('Please type your name\n'))
        print('Welcome ' + name.title() + '.\n')

input_age() #Execute age function
```

Comment: Checking for int is redundant since you explicitly convert the value to int. If it can't be converted (a string for example) you'll simply get an exception.

Comment: `age = int(input('Please enter your age\n'))`  age will definitely be `int`

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple methods that could be used to determine data types in this situation - however, each is slightly different. Python has the **`Type()`** function. Though this function has three parameters `type(object, bases, dict)`, only one is required, the object. If you would like to learn about the other parameters, look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_type.asp). You can use an if else statement to determine if the object type is a string -

```
import sys #to be used for error message

user_input = input("prompt")
input_type = Type(user_input)

if input_type == int:
  do_whatever()
else:
  sys.exit("Please try again with an integer input")
```

However, due to the nature of the input() function, this will not work in this instance, as input() always returns a string - however, the other two methods are still valid.

Another method is to use an Exception, as mentioned by Sruthi V. When converting to an integer, if a string is inputted, an error will occur.

```
try:
  user_input = input("prompt")
  user_input = int(user_input)
except ValueError:
  print("Please run the program again and enter an integer")
```

Finally, you can use the **`isinstance()`** function - essentially an alternative to the Type function. `isinstance()` takes two values, `(object, type)`. A bool of true or false will be returned, depending on if the type of object is the same as the parameter `type`.

```
import sys

user_input = input("prompt")
if isinstance(user_input, int):
  do_whatever()
else:
  sys.exit('Run the program again with an integer input')
```

However, you already check for int at the beginning of your file - an error will occur if any value that is not an int is detected. Therefore, in your specific situation, there is no need to check if the value is int. You may use exceptions to print custom messages on input of a non-integer value, but checking if the value is an int again is repetitive, and uses unnecessary resources.

Comment: `input` will only ever return a `str` object.

Comment: Also, W3 schools is a really bad resource

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that is correct - in this situation the `type` function wouldn't work. I did not consider that. However, the other two are still valid

Comment: Well, no, `isinstance` won't work for the exact same reason.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga however, it is not really relevant, as the int() function at the beginning does all of the work needed - I am just writing this for future viewers who stumble across this for similar problems. It does not have to be the exact same.

Comment: I'm not sure how this post is helpful to future readers. Two of the code samples simply don't work.

Comment: @Mark in the case someone is searching for checking data types in general. However I understand your concerns.